# Update the tar. bz2 compressed file

Tags: bash, shell

We have 100 hundreds of file in trx_date.tar.bz2 compressed file which has request and response . below is file structure of  trx_date.tar.bz2 : trx_date.tar: trx_date contains : log1 ,log2,log3 files which has xml request  having some sensitive info and i would like to mask it to some default value. Request Request is having tag 1234567 and i want to mask it to i.e update it to log file to 3333333

I am able to grep it using the the :

```
Number1=bzcat $LOGDIR/$LOG_FORMAT | grep "<number>[0-2,4-9][0-2,4-9][0-2,4-9][0-2,4-9][0-2,4-9][0-2,4-9][0-2,4-9]"
```

how we can override the those value in the log files using shell script ?

Log file contains request and response.. Where we have tag like 123456 and also other tags as well . I want to read all the line of log file and replace that specific tag like below 333333 and save the info into same file. We have info tag with 333333 as well but I don't want to consider that.

Comment: Tag name let's consider it as <number>value</number>

Comment: Not  clear at all, please provide more details(may be samples of input and expected output) in your post with CODE TAGS `{}` button and let us know then.

Comment: Log file contains request and response.. Where we have tag like <info>123456</info> and also other tags as well . I want to read all the line of log file and replace that specific tag like below <info>333333</info> and save the info into same file. We have info tag with <info>333333</info> as well but I don't want to consider that.

Comment: The approximate number of files and data volume (e.g. total uncompressed archive size in gigabytes, typical file size in megabytes) should go into the question.

Comment: If we will cron the script and run the script for only one file at a time.  Disk space won't be an issue

Comment: By the by, `Number1=bzcat $LOGDIR/$LOG_FORMAT` does not do what you appear to hope it does. It will attempt to execute `$LOGDIR/$LOG_FORMAT` as a command, with the variable `Number1` set to the string `bzcat` for the duration of this execution attempt. You probably want a comcand substitution `Number1=$(bzcat ...)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, you cannot do directly what you want (without extracting the file from your `.tar.bz2` compressed archive), since a `.tar.bz2` file is a bzip2-ed compression of a  [`tar` archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)). So the only good solution would be to extract files from the archive, do the modification on the extracted files (e.g. with [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) or [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)), and recreate an archive from it. Using `sed` on *one particular textual file* to replace a pattern like `<number>[0-9]*</number>` by `<number>0000000</number>` is easy. Writing a bash [`for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html) to iterate that on several files is easy. So combine both approaches, or write a tiny shell or Python script doing that (on the *extracted* files).

In practice (but that is risky and I don't recommend that) you could hope that `<number>` digits `</number>` happens only in the files part of the `tar` archive you want to modify in place, and then you could perhaps replace (directly in the *uncompressed* `tar` archive), using e.g. [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html), such sequences with other sequences *of the same byte length* (read more about the `tar` format: meta data such as file sizes appear in textual form, <kbd>NUL</kbd> bytes completed).

You might also consider using [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/), a tar post-processor (that you need to install).

I strongly recommend extracting the tar archive, operate on the extracted files, then recreate that archive again. Of course, you need enough disk space, and you have to estimate it. But tell your manager that disk space is cheap, generally cheaper than your labor costs.

PS. The command given in your question is really wrong and does not do what you dream of. Read more about [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)), [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), [unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). Read carefully the [documentation of Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/) (notably [basic shell features](http://ttps://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Basic-Shell-Features.html), [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)). **Read** also **the documentation of each command that you want to use**, e.g. [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html), [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html), etc....). Read the relevant [man-pages(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html) perhaps with the [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) command.

Comment: We have around 200+ files and every files is around 25mb zipped size.. So it will create disk space issue in server I believe.. Anyways I can't see any other way.  I can try file by file.  Can you help with below. Lets consider weread the file uncompreesd file and stored it to variable. Now I'm iterating thorough the file line by line and once we got <info>123456</info> . I want to replace it to <info>333333</info> and save it to same file

Comment: No, I won't write your script. If you have disk space issues, discuss with your manager: buying more disk is probably cheaper than the time you'll need to find a workaround (because your development time has some cost, and because disk space is cheap)

Comment: Updated my previous comment ..i can avoid disk space issue other way.

Comment: That is your (and your manager's and your organization's) problem. However, consider your labor cost vs disk space cost. My daily labor cost is bigger than the cost of a terabyte of disk. Are you paid so little w.r.t. disk space cost? You should estimate the required disk space and speak to your manager about its cost.

Comment: Aligned With your  suggestions